# how to get rails to update Oracle xml_type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, oracle

I'm having problems getting rails to update Oracle xml_type column.

I select the entry using the find method

```
myobj = find(id)
```

And then attempt to update it using:

```
myobj.update_attribute(:the_column_name, new_content)
```

The method completes without any errors but the column is not updated.

I verify that other attributes can be updated correctly using the same method call:

```
myobj.update_attributes(:the_column_name=>new_content, status=>2)
```

I also verify that when I do:

```
ModelClassName.update_all(:the_xml_colum_name=>new_content)
```

The rows actually do get updated.
Which makes me confused. The update_all method updates the xml column allright but update_attributes on a single row does not (while it correctly updates non-xml attributes).

I'm using jruby with activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (1.4.2) and Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 0):

I have no explanation for this but it seems to work when I do update_where without selecting first:

```
 ModelClassName.where(<condition>).update_all(:the_xml_column_name => new_content)
```